# RandomReal closed on left & open on right?

Tags: numerics, random, implementation-details

I have a number of algorithms that depend on uniform random reals in half-open intervals such as $[0,1)$. In particular, I need a (pseudo) random-number generator that produces machine-precision numbers in the range $0.0$ to $1-\epsilon$. It can return $0.999...$, but will never return exactly $1.0$. I haven't found in the Mathematica documentation whether Mathematica's `RandomReal` satisfies this requirement. The documentation does state that `RandomInteger[{xMin,xMax}]` produces values in the double-closed interval $[x_{min}, x_{max}]$ inclusive of both ends, but I haven't found an equally clear statement about the real-number generators. The documentation that I've read just says "between 0 and 1." I could read this as double-open, but it really isn't precise enough for me. I would be grateful for an authoritative answer.

Comment: Well, which algorithm are you using, first of all?

Comment: Given that if `1.0` is possible, it is still a rare event, you could just write a function which tests for `1.0` and otherwise tries again, say `rightOpenRandomReal[] := Module[{rr = RandomReal[]}, If[rr == 1.0, rightOpenRandomReal[], rr]]`

Comment: @J.M. I have many algorithms carried over from the world of regular programming, where `rand` typically satisfies my requirement. I'm sure that some of my algorithms can be rewritten using `RandomInteger`, in particular those algorithms that generate array indices, e.g., Walker's method of aliases.  However, I would still like to have a uniform $[0,1)$ in my tool chest so that I am not forced to rewrite at that level.

Comment: ... I was asking about [which PRNG generator](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/RandomNumberGeneration.html#185956823) are you using. If, e.g., you're using `"Congruential"`, then yes, you will hit $0$ and/or $1$, depending on your choice of multiplier and modulus. `"MersenneTwister"` might hit $0$, but it won't hit $1$.

Comment: @J.M. oh, i gotcha.  Mersenne will be good for me!  Promote that recommendation and I will mark it as answer.

Comment: It might be more profitable for you to wait for a more comprehensive answer. I for one do not know how the default CA-based PRNG method (`"ExtendedCA"`) behaves...

Comment: @J.M.: How do you know that reals generated with the Mersenne Twister won't take the value 1?

Comment: @celtschk FWIW `SeedRandom[Method -> "MersenneTwister"]` *will* generate `1.`'s if the range is compressed, e.g. `Count[RandomReal[{1 - 100 $MachineEpsilon, 1}, 1000], 1.]`

Comment: @celtschk: that's my understanding of the description in the Matsumoto/Nishimura paper...

Comment: Thanks for the Accept. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard only took me what, five years to get to it? /slaps forehead

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing some complexity to this issue but why can you not simply use:

```
RandomReal[1 - $MachineEpsilon, 10]
```

The limit certainly appears to work.  For example:

```
Count[RandomReal[{1 - 100 $MachineEpsilon, 1}, 5*^6], 1.]
```

> ```
> 37447
> ```

```
Count[RandomReal[{1 - 100 $MachineEpsilon, 1 - $MachineEpsilon}, 5*^6], 1.]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

The first line shows that at least when using this restricted range the upper bound is closed.  This shows that lower bound is closed as well:

```
Count[RandomReal[{1 - 100 $MachineEpsilon, 1}, 5*^6], 1 - 100 $MachineEpsilon]
```

> ```
> 12433
> ```

Comment: I essentially asked this in a comment, before I edited it out and deleted it. The reason was because upon closer reading, I realized that the OP was asking for an authoritative reference on how `RandomReal` works, not an implementation — _"I haven't found an equally clear statement about the real-number generators. The documentation that I've read just says "between 0 and 1." I could read this as double-open, but it really isn't precise enough for me. I would be grateful for an authoritative answer."_ Your answer assumes that `RandomReal` generates on a closed interval, but you have no proof.

Comment: @rm-rf *"Your answer assumes that RandomReal generates on a closed interval, but you have no proof."*  My answer shows plainly that at least when given a tightly restricted range it does.

Comment: @rm-rf Now I think you're just being stubborn.  Clearly I have shown that the `1 - $MachineEpsilon` and `1` produce different results when used as the upper bound.  Exactly what are you looking for?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I think, for practical purposes, your answer solves my problem. I will wait a little bit before marking it to see if some new insight appears.  BTW, your use of `Count` and `1-100 $MachineEpsilon` is very useful and helpful.

Comment: Assuming that internal PRNGs follow the same rules which are imposed on self-defined PRNGs, the following quote from [Random Number Generation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/RandomNumberGeneration.html) should be at least a strong hint that the interval borders are included: "If random reals are supported, then `gobj["GenerateReals"[n, {a, b}, prec]]` is expected to return a list of n random reals with precision prec in the range `[a,b]`" — note the square brackets.

Comment: I love Mma, but this is an example where inadequacy of documentation combined with lack of access to the source leaves us guessing about something where there should be no guessing.

Comment: @Alan No argument from me on that point.